# Confusion over rate of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The rate of convergence defined as: 
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|x_{k+1}-a|}{|x_{k}-a|} =\mu$$

seems to mean that a sequence with a higher $\mu$ should have a higher rate of convergence ie. should converge faster to its limit.

I find that the opposite is true, as for $x_{n+1}=\mu x_{n}+c$ , with$|\mu|<1$, it converges faster as $\mu$ is closer to zero.

Why such a counterintuitive definition? Am I missing something?

Comment: Interesting. What source is this from?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368040/rate-of-convergence-definition?rq=1 may be of help or interest

Comment: It should be called "convergence ratio". The difference between the sequence and its limit is apporixmately a geometric progression with a common ratio $\mu$ hence the name.